Why is Volume the Integral of Area?
Consider a solid $S$ situated on the $x$-axis in the interval $[a,b]$ with cross sectional area $A(x)$. You can find in many calculus textbooks, such as Stewart, that
$$
\text{Volume}(S) = \int_a^b\!A(x)\, dx.
$$
Can this be justified under simple axioms for volume? I am looking for a way to justify this to a Calculus I class. While the intuition of "infinitesimal slices integrate to a solid" is extremely important, I do not find it rigorous enough on its own.
As an example of what I mean, consider the region $R$ under a curve $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$. Using only the facts that area of a rectangle is length times width, that the area of sets is a monotone function under set inclusions, and that area is finitely additive (the same axioms we use in measure theory!), we have that
$$
L^*_n  \leq \text{Area}(R) \leq U^*_n 
$$
for all $n$, where $L^*_n$ and $U^*_n$ are, respectively the lower and upper Darboux sums for
$$
\int_a^b \!f(x)\,dx.
$$
Therefore, when you take limits as $n$ goes to infinity, the squeeze theorem yields
$$
\text{Area}(R) = \int_a^b \!f(x)\,dx.
$$
However, when you do the same for volumes, you don't necessarily have that the portion of $S$ on the interval $[a + i\Delta x, a+(i +1) \Delta x]$ is a subset of the corresponding cylinder in the Darboux sum. I suppose you could cut up $S$ to fit inside the cylinder, but this is very handwavy unless you really dig down into the epsilons and deltas.

After posting, I suppose that this could be explained using double integrals and Fubini's Theorem, and I would not be surprised if this were the best answer. However, maybe there are other ways to explain it the single integral way.

Fubini is the best answer. I will be surprised if there is a better one.
